# echoing text field value in a while loop

Tags: php

```
echo " <table bgcolor='#d3fcfe'   align='center'>  ";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo '</div> <tr onmouseout="this.bgColor=\'#d3fcfe\';"  onmouseover= "this   .bgColor=\'#fffdcd\';" >  ';
 $numq2=$row['username'] ;


{
echo '<td ><div class="iddiv"> <input name="" type="text" value="$numq2" />   <div>    </td> ';
}

echo '  </table>';
}
```

i want to output $numq2 Var's data into the value of the textfield.but something is wrong with my code.it prinout   the value of textfield as "$numq2".what's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
echo '<td ><div class="iddiv"> <input name="" type="text" value="$numq2" />   <div>    </td> ';
```

should become

```
echo '<td ><div class="iddiv"> <input name="" type="text" value="'.$numq2.'" />   <div>    </td> ';
```

Notice the `'.` and `.'` around your `$numq2`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use double quotes `"` for your strings in order for variables to be evaluated.  Escape the double quotes in your HTML to have one long string.

Alternatively, you can use concatenation, allowing you to use single quotes around your HTML, and then concatenating the evaluated variables in between, like so:

```
echo '<td ><div class="iddiv"> <input name="" type="text" value="'.$numq2.'" />   <div>    </td> ';
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use your echo like this:

```
echo '<td ><div class="iddiv"> <input name="" type="text" value="' . $row['username'] . '" />   <div>    </td> ';
```

Answer (score 1):

wrong quote use.

use either

```
echo '...value="'.$numq2.'" />...';
```

or

```
echo " ... value=\"$numq2\" /> ...";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes around your string.

Anything wrapped in single quotes gets output as is, and does not get parsed.

Double quotes runs your string through the parser and any variables get replaced with their values.

You need to either break out of the single quotes and concatenate your variable as follows:

```
echo 'My value ' . $value . ' is the best value';
```

Or you need to wrap your string in double quotes and wrap your variable in { } as follows:

```
echo "My value {$value} is the best value";
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo <td ><div class="iddiv"> <input name="" type="text" value="<?php echo $numq2;?>" />   <div></td>';
```